# How to update items inside a state aysnchronously

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state:

```
this.state = {
  data: [
    {id: 1212, cat:"cat1"},
    {id: 13123, cat:"cat1"},
    {id: 1212, cat:"cat2"},
    {id: 13123, cat:"cat2"},
    {id: 1212, cat:"cat3"},
    {id: 13123, cat:"cat3"},
    {id: 1212, cat:"cat4"},
    {id: 13123, cat:"cat4"},
    ..
  ]
}
```

I have ids and cat (categories). All the data is dynamic.I dont know which ids and cats will be fetched everytime

```
in the componentDidMount(){
  // I fetch the latest data and sort it based on cat and  `setState` for `this.state.data`
}

in the componentDidUpdate(){
  // I will get the all the unique cats from this.state.data and store it in an array.
  // I will loop over the unique cats and fetch some more data related to each cat. But this will be aynchronous
  // Now how to add the fetched data for each cat at all the places wherever that cat is there in the this.state.data

  // i.e
    i am expecting this.state.data to be
      {
        data: [
          {id: 1212, cat:"cat1", extra:'....'},
          {id: 13123, cat:"cat1", extra:'....'},
          {id: 1212, cat:"cat2", extra:'....'},
          {id: 13123, cat:"cat2", extra:'....'},
          {id: 1212, cat:"cat3", extra:'....'},
          {id: 13123, cat:"cat3", extra:'....'},
          {id: 1212, cat:"cat4", extra:'....'},
          {id: 13123, cat:"cat4", extra:'....'},
          ..
        ]
      }

}
```

How to add new property to the data based on that particulat cat aysnchronously.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--same was as you'd handle any other async task: make the request, update the state when it's done. Depending on your needs you might want to wait until all the fetches have completed, though, otherwise you may force a bunch of re-renders before you're truly ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update state inside of `componentDidUpdate`, because it would immediately cause an infinite loop.  You update state, the component re-renders, `componentDidUpdate` calls, you update state, etc.

Instead, you need to put all of this information into your `componentDidMount` hook.  It's ok to call `setState` multiple times here.

Do your initial fetch, and set the data to your state.  Then, within this same method, do your subsequent data fetches.  As you receive new data, update a local method variable for `data` and call `setState` again with the new version of `data`.

Comment: componentdidmount will run only once. can you give some code in this regard.

Comment: Also i want to know how to update a array where things are not grouped. Also when i am calling four updates at a time, will reactjs do it in sequence or all at a time